# Not being prompted for credentials when connecting to a share on different domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, network-share

We are a computer repair shop.  When working on client machines, we connect them to our network and map a network share that resides inside our domain to store an image of the hard drive.  Up until yesterday, when using Explorer to map the network drive, we were always automatically presented with a username\password prompt. However, as of today, Windows just maps the share, but obviously we get an "Access denied." error when trying to open the share because we didn't supply any credentials.

Any ideas as to why this started happening today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion that somebody enabled the "Guest" account in your domain. Have a look at that.

Comment: GENIUS !!!! You saved the day for us...

Comment: Glad I could help.